# What is the dependency of the IsFieldExcluded method?

Tags: template

I have created a custom ListForm template and overide the IsFieldExcluded method. I am wondering why some fields in my situation are returning true and others are returning false.

What is the dependency of the value of the method:

IsFieldExcluded(Microsoft.SharePoint.SPField field)

Is it maybe if the field is set on hidden in the content type or something?? When is a field excluded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following parameters indicates whether the specified field is excluded when the [ListFieldIterator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms443299.aspx) is rendered.

### [SPField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms438369.aspx) properties

- [ShowInDisplayForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.showindisplayform.aspx) - value that specifies whether the field is
  displayed in the form for displaying list items
- [ShowInNewForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.showinnewform.aspx) - value that specifies whether the field is
  displayed in the form that is used to create list items
- [ShowInEditForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.showineditform.aspx) - value that specifies whether the field is
  displayed in the form that is used to edit list items
- [Hidden](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.hidden.aspx) - value that specifies whether the field is displayed in
  the list
- [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.type.aspx) - value that specifies the type of field. Depending on [control modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spcontrolmode.aspx) some field types are not rendered, for example field with type [PageSeparator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldpageseparator.aspx) is not rendered in *Display* mode
- [InternalName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.internalname.aspx) - Gets the internal name that is used for the field. For example field identified by internal name "ContentType" (*Content Type*) is not rendered.
- [SPFieldCalculated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldcalculated.aspx) - Represents a calculated field in a list. This field is rendered in *Display* [control mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spcontrolmode.aspx) only.

---

### [ListFieldIterator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms473273.aspx) properties

- [ExcludeFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.listfielditerator.excludefields.aspx) - the fields that are not rendered

Answer (score 0):

According to the MSDN: Gets a value that indicates whether the specified field is excluded when the ListFieldIterator is rendered.

For more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.listfielditerator.isfieldexcluded.aspx